# Can i customize the iPhone Lock Button?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am trying to make an App to start working when the user unlock the iPhone
so is it possible to call the application to foreground when the user hit the lock button in other words can I connect the unlock event with running an application?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to customise the behaviour of the lock button.

Comment: *Insert comment about how it's possible on jailbroken phones*.

Comment: is there any way to call my app when the user just hit lock button ??